# How should I implement a CollectionView with inherited entities?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, collections

I'm new at WPF/C# and I have a question about binding Collections using Entity Framework.

I have a base Entity"Order" (Commande in french)  and I used Inheritance per type to regroup them in fonctionnal topics : by instance : Order_Doc, Order_Check , ...

I put controls on tabitem with each item containing a panel of controls I'd like to bind with child entity fields.
So I'm searching an elegant solution to fill these tab items with the associated Child Entity.

As yet, I've managed to bind controls with data belonging to the base Class Order and to walk through the collection.

I've declared a CollectionViewSource based on Orders.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSourceCommandes" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance src:Commande, CreateList=True}"/>                
</Window.Resources>
```

When the window is loaded I Initialise the collection of Orders (commandes)

```
CommandesViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("ViewSourceCommandes")));
ObjectQuery<Commande> CommandesQuery = this.GetCommandesQuery(contexte);                       
CommandesViewSource.Source = CommandesQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

The function GetCommandesQuery is simple :

```
private ObjectQuery<Commande> GetCommandesQuery(ModelContainer CommandeEntities)
{            
    ObjectQuery<Commande> CommandesQuery = CommandeEntities.Commandes;            
    return CommandesQuery;
}
```

I can walk through the collection by this function :

```
private void buttonFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 NumCommande = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxNumCommande.Text);
    Commande commandeItem = contexte.Commandes.Where("it.NumCommande = @NumCommande", new ObjectParameter("NumCommande", NumCommande)).FirstOrDefault();
    CommandesViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(commandeItem);
}
```

Some controls on my main Window are binded on "Commande" fields : I can get the right content for them.
But there's also in this main Window a TabControl in which I'd like to feed TabItems with 
inherited classes as Commande_Doc, Commande_Check, ... and to bind controls on their fields.

What is the best way to implement this elegantly ? I'm a bit lost ...

Thanks by advance.